# On Windows, when will a 'socket()' call return WSAEAFNOSUPPORT?

Tags: sockets, winapi, networking, winsock2

Suppose our client application does as below:

```
WSADATA wsa_data;
int     ret;
SOCKET  sock;
ret = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsa_data);
if (ret ==0) {
  sock = socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPROTO_UDP);
}
```

When will it happen that `sock == INVALID_SOCKET` and `WSAGetLastError()` would return `WSAEAFNOSUPPORT`?

Microsoft's documentation for the `socket()` function says it can return `WSAEAFNOSUPPORT` when:

> The specified address family is not supported

I have seen that this error mainly comes if I am explicitly passing a wrong address family for the given protocol.

Is there a possibility that the address family is not supported by the OS itself (ie, it is not configured in the system itself) and this error can come during a `socket()` call?

If yes, why? Under what circumstances? And how can it be remedied?

Comment: If you run this on Windows 2000 or earlier you will probably get this error because it doesn't support IPv6

Comment: Thanks @user253751 . If this error comes on Windows 2000 or earlier then what are the possible remedies to resolve this issue?

Comment: update windows? maybe one day  they'll invent IPv7 and then it won't work on Windows 11

Comment: it might also be possible to fully uninstall IPv6 on windows versions that normally do support it - not sure. Did you read what the meaning of the error is?

Comment: It's not something I've messed with directly, but I am almost positive IPv6 was an optional component on some historic versions of Windows, i.e. you could go into the TCP/IP settings on the adapter and disable it (IPv4 too, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

[Examples of base transport providers include base protocol stacks such as TCP/IP or IPX/SPX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/about-the-winsock-spi). [Transport and namespace service providers must be registered with the Ws2_32.dll at the time they are installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/transport-configuration-and-installation-2).

Applications calling either socket or WSASocket trigger that Ws2_32.dll loads the provider DLLs using *the standard Microsoft Windows dynamic library loading mechanisms* and then invokes [WSPStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Ws2spi/nf-ws2spi-wspstartup) and [WSPSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2spi/nc-ws2spi-lpwspsocket#remarks).

[When one of the providers doesn't support the passed AddressFamily , WSPSocket returns WSAEAFNOSUPPORT](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/lsp/nonifslsp/spi.cpp#L3181).